# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' in .Net core mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm getting ‍`Object reference not set to an instance of an object` in following code

```
hbprint = await _vw_BPS.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id);

foreach (var hbs in hbprint.Vw_hcsp)          
{   
    var stock = await _vw_hcsp.FindAsync(x=> x.HId == id);
          
    var svm= new Vw_hcsp
    {
        HId = stock.HId,
        HBLContainerId = stock.HBLContainerId,
        Chassis_No = stock.Chassis_No,
        ContainerNo = stock.ContainerNo,
        Seal_No = stock.Seal_No,
        Vehicle_Model = stock.Vehicle_Model,
        Gross_Weight_Stock = stock.Gross_Weight_Stock,
        Volume_Stock = stock.Volume_Stock
     };
}
```

Comment: Hii Samiksha, Does your code have any value in stock after the FindAsync() methods execution?

Comment: No, when control goes to hbprint.Vw_hcsp it is showing me that exception.

Comment: That means either hbprint after this line hbprint = await _vw_BPS.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id); is null that is there is no hbprint for the id which your passing. otherwise hbprint doesn't have a property Vw_hcsp.Debugging would help you to find the reason.

Comment: hbprint has property Vw_hcsp.

Comment: Does it hold any value? Can you tell me the tool(Visual studio/VS Code) you are using ?

Comment: Vw_hcsp is a model class and have used it as Icollection in vw_BP model class. There are values in database but it is  showing null values here . I am using Visual studio.

Comment: As you are using Visual studio, place a break point at this line                               
  hbprint = await _vw_BPS.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id); add a dummy line of code like var a = hbprint. press F10 Now hover over   hbprint, expand it and share the screenshot here

Comment: When I used List<Vw_hcsp> model = new List<Vw_hcsp>(); it's not showing me that error. I placed breakpoint there but it is showing me empty list.

Comment: Yes it will show an empty list only because you are creating an empty list with this line  List<Vw_hcsp> model = new List<Vw_hcsp>();.could you please keep a break point here "hbprint = await _vw_BPS.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id);" and share me the data in that via a screenshot. We can proceed to next step after this step.